# Cancancan create authorization still lets create form to be shown to other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

All the other authorizations for other forms are working fine. But for this create form below, the authorization keeps letting the form to be seen by others.

```rb
<%= form_for([@book]) do |form| %>
```

Authorization code:

```rb
<% if can? :create, @book %>
```

When I switch @book to Book or [@user, @book] or [@book, @post], none works. @user, @book hides the form to both the current user and other users.

What can I do?

Ability.rb:

````rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.present?
      can :read, Book
      can :read, Post
      can :read, Comment
      can :manage, Book, user_id: user.id
      can :manage, Post, book: { user: { id: user.id } }      
      can :manage, Comment, post: { book: { user: { id: user.id }}}

    end
```
````

Comment: Can you show us your ability files?

Comment: @morissetcl certainly - updated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think your mistake is Here:

`can :manage, Book, user_id: user.id`

Basically in `create` action your object has no `user_id` yet because your object is not saved. So you should update your ability files with the following code:

```
can [:read, :create], Book
can [:destroy, :update], Book, user_id: user. id
```

Let me know.

**Edit**

Ok I Am missing a point. You have a Statement to check if you have a `current_user` above, so I think you don't need to add `user_id:` in your `Book`  ability.

Can you please try: `can manage, Book`

Also be sure to restart your server, sometimes abilities can be capricious.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've tried it, and it unfortunately doesn't seem to work. So ```Book and @book``` show the form to both types of users, and ```@user, @book or User, Book``` hides the view from both users.

Comment: Thank you - I will check the code later today. Sorry about the delay.